# Error in loadNamespace when trying to install R package 'lifecycle'

Tags: r

I am using R 3.5.3 on my corporate PC and wanted to install a few packages like "IRkernel" or "ggplot2" which both have some dependencies. One of these dependent packages is 'lifecycle'. When trying to install the package using the command:

```
install.packages('lifecycle')
```

I receive the error:

*Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc), .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required.*

I already...

- deinstalled and reinstalled R
- changed R_LIBS_USER to another folder on the C drive (C:/Users/myname/R) using a local environment variable
- tried to install the package on another machine with a more recent R version (4.0.2), which worked.

Any ideas how to solve this without having to upgrade the R version?

Comment: You may have luck checking cran for an older version of `lifecycle` that relies on an older version of `rlang`.

Comment: Note that `rlang` is a package, not R itself. The current version `0.4.10` is compatible with R `>=3.3.0`, so it should be fine with `3.5.3`. Try updating `rlang` directly.

Comment: Do you have an .RProfile file that automatically loads packages at startup? Try going to your lib folder and manually deleting the `rlang` folder (or moving it to another location) with R is closed; then reopen R and try to install the package.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I tried install.packages('lifecycle', version = '0.2.0') and received the same error. Maybe the version argument in the install.packages function is not considered at all. However, I receive no message regarding this.

I tried install.packages('rlang') assuming it gives me the latest version and then in a second step tried to install lifecycle - same result. Or did I get the update wrong?

Have no .RProfile set up, removed rlang and repeated installing it - worked (but did also before). However, the issue for lifecycle persists.

Comment: Did you restart R after installing rlang 0.4.10, before trying to install lifecycle? Note that there is no version argument for `install.packages()`, you can see this if you look at the docs with `?install.packages`. The easiest way to install a specific version of a package is with `devtools::install_version()`. You can check what version of rlang R is currently seeing with `packageVersion()`.

Comment: @CalumYou After trying again the installation after restart I finally found a way to get a more recent R version where no such issue came up. Thanks anyway.